# Docker cloud node BYON is unreachable

Tags: docker, cloud, docker-compose, orchestration

We are switching to Docker Cloud, with bring your own node BYON use, since we can't use public cloud providers.

For some reason Node is often times **Unreachable**, and it becomes Reachable, only for some time when I restart container.

Server is running behind firewall, but 2375 & 6738 ports are open.

What can this be?

I think the problem is DNS name generate by docker-cloud incorrect and uses wrong IP, so if I override it, it should work, but I'm not sure how to do it.